# How to apply filter in documentdb dynamically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, azure-cosmosdb, azure-hub

I am sending one request to my nodejs server which is using documentdb as database.

```
Ex./student/:classId?studentId=1234&name=piyush&age=14&gender=male&class=12
```

this request url is fixed till `Ex./student/:classId` but remaning part is dynamic that may come, may not come.

Now if I am getting querystring params then I want to apply filter in my documentdb query.

```
var query = {
        query: 'SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.classId=@classIdAND r.collectionName="students"',
        parameters: [{
            name: '@classId',
            value: classId
        }]
    };

    docDbClient.queryDocuments(collection._self, query).toArray(function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }
        callback(null, results[0]);
    });
```

so here classId will come that is for sure but remaining params are not fixed so I want write that type of query which can filter like this: suppose I am passing just age then it should filter collection by just age, suppose I am passing all other params like. studentId, name, age, gender then it should filter data with all params, again this params are not defined they are dynamic so I don't know name of these params when I am writing query so I want to apply filter based on coming params,

so how can I write this query?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it without hand generating the `WHERE` clause or coming up with every combination. This is exactly the use case that caused me to create the [sql-from-mongo npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-from-mongo).

Using your example, this part of your query string:

```
studentId=1234&name=piyush&age=14&gender=male&class=12
```

gets translated into something like this JSON by your HTTP server handler:

```
myQuerySpec = {
  studentId: 1234,
  name: "piyush",
  age: 14,
  gender: "male",
  class: 12
};
```

The numbers may come in as strings or numbers so you may have to tweak the types for the numbers depending upon how your HTTP server handler translates those and whether or not you are storing them as integers (probably age and class) or strings (probably studentId). However, once you have the JSON the way you want, you can then pass that along to sql-from-mongo like this:

```
query = "SELECT c.fieldA, c.fieldB FROM c WHERE " + sqlFromMongo(myQuerySpec, 'c');
```

or if you want it to automatically create the boilerplate:

```
query = sqlFromMongo(myQuerySpec, "c", ["fieldA", "fieldB"])
```

or if you want it to automatically get all the fields:

```
query = sqlFromMongo(myQuerySpec, "c", "*")
```

Note, the query created by sql-from-mongo is immune to injection attacks due to proper escaping of strings. So, while we were all taught to used parameterized SQL queries to avoid the risk of SQL injection, you are safe using a string generated with sql-from-mongo.

Comment: it is throwing error for me in documentdb query, but working in mongodb, so how can I run in documentdb?

Comment: This is for documentdb:

myQuerySpec = {
  studentId: 1234,
  name: "piyush",
  age: 14,
  gender: "male",
  class: 12
};

queryspec: {
 query: 'SELECT * FROM root r WHERE '+sqlFromMongo(myQuerySpec, 'r')+' AND r.collectionName="students"'
}

Comment: You need an equal sign after `queryspec` not a colon

Comment: ohhh sorry by mistake I have added colon here, not in my code, it is equal in my code, though its throwing error.

Comment: syntax error in query near "sqlFromMongo(myQuerySpec" in error response.

Comment: have you any demo code for nodejs & documentdb which can fulfill this?